# Privacy: Runtime vs. Native Code

Tags: android, ios, security, runtime, privacy

Please forgive me naievity on this subject if I've missed something. I'm a .NET programmer and have dabbled in Java in the past. It strikes me that code compiled for a runtime environment like .NET or Java - assuming that those runtime environments are fairly secure, can be reasonably guaranteed not to break any OS level rules about what the app can and can't do based on permissions.

My understanding is that Apple does not allow runtime environments on iOS, and will eventually phase them out on OSX. My understanding is that Apple app store apps are compiled to Native code.

So, my understanding is that any tool that analyses an Apple app store application for malware would have a lot harder time figuring out if the app is breaking any of the OS level rules about permissions. My understanding is that if you wanted to, you could compile assembly code in to your app. Apple's analysis tools could potentially pick that up - but I imagine that they would not always be sophisticated enough to figure out that some spyware or malware had made it in to an app store app.

Of course, there are security holes with .NET based technology and Java technology. So, there is always a chance that an app might find a loophole and leak some of your information or do something nasty. But, all in all, it should be a lot easier for Android and Windows to find issues with app store apps because these apps don't run Native code.

Are my assumptions correct? Does this mean that potentially, some iOS apps may contain hidden malware that the analysing tools have missed? Isn't this going to become a bigger issue for Apple in future?

Comment: You submit compiled binaries to Apple, not source code, so "compiling assembly code into your app" is meaningless; All Apple has to work with is the assembly code, regardless of the source language.  True, they get some help from things like symbol tables to try detect private API usage.  The App sandbox is engineered to be secure, not because apps "obey the rules" but because they are prohibited from doing certain things - think speed limit vs speed limiter on a car.

Comment: "You submit compiled binaries to Apple, not source code". Exactly. When you submit binaries to Microsoft or Google, you are submitting code that is compiled to an intermediate language which is not machine code. This code can be clearly interpreted. However, all Apple has to work with is machine code. My point is basically that it seems that it would be harder for Apple to interpret machine code than say MSIL. How can Apple be sure that machine code is obeying the rules?

Comment: The problem with Java (at least in the past) is that the runtime itself often runs with elevated privileges, so if the app manages to "break out" then it has elevated privileges too.  Apps on iOS run as Unix process and although privilege escalation vulnerabilities have been found in the past (and will be in the future) you are starting from a more secured environment.  Although .Net is probably more secure than Java, the introduction of the runtime environment introduces another layer that needs to be secured.

Comment: Whether you submit an IL or native code it doesn't matter.  IL is just machine code for a virtual processor; vulnerabilities occur because apps make calls that they aren't permitted to or execute arbitrary code through buffer overruns and the like.  The runtime environment introduces more opportunities for bugs that can be exploited.  Running native code allows stronger protection of data vs. code, address space randomisation etc.

Comment: " Running native code allows stronger protection of data vs. code". Hence why I said "Please forgive me naievity on this subject". Can you elaborate on this? Perhaps point to some documentation on this? On its face, it doesn't ring true to me, but that may just be because I don't understand it. What I don't grasp is how an app store analyzer could be able to look at some given machine code in an iOS app submitted to the store, and figure out whether or not it breaks any of the permissions that the app doesn't have. How does it know that there's just not some nasty hidden assembly code?

Comment: This is why I said "think speed limiter not speed limit".  The app cannot break the rules and use permissions it doesn't have.  If the speed limit is 60 you can choose to drive 70, but if the car is limited to 60 by the engine computer the driver can't go faster than 60 even if they want to.  Apple puts protections in the sandbox so that an app, for example, can't access the device contacts without asking permission and getting approval for the user.  Accessing the contacts without permission isn't a choice the app can make.  See https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf pg18

Comment: Yes. I guess the crux of what I don't understand is how an app compiled to native code can have a "sandbox". In a runtime environment, everything is sandboxed by default. How does Apple insure that native code runs inside a "sandbox"? Are you able to point me to the section of this document that explains how sandboxing works on iOS?

Comment: I mean the word "sandboxed" is used a lot in this document. But, what does it mean? If the app just simply chooses to execute some machine code that works outside of the sandbox, what protections exist to stop that from happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123298/discussion-between-paulw11-and-melbourne-developer).

Comment: Here is a relevant article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)

Comment: This is very informative from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Comment: That document is about App Sandboxing on OS X, not iOS.  iOS uses an even more restrictive sandbox

Comment: Windows Store 8.1 and UWP isn't based on IL (there is no .NET runtime). Also now you have Desktop Bridge (Win32 via the Store in redirected/isolated [not container-based] environment)